# Replace existing file and push to top index of array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to push the current file that I find in the if statement if it is true, to the top item ... so I find it and transfer it to the top ....

```
  allProducts.forEach(
    (product) =>
      checkIfProductIsMoreThen200(product.price) && 
      allProducts.unshift(product)
  );
```

this is my try but no work...

he pushes me into the top index
but leave me the old items ... and then it duplicates my current ones ... I don't want to duplicate the items ..

Comment: what is `arr` -  that is what you're putting to the top of `allAttachments` - but what is it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i am edit question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), it should do the trick for you.

```js
const allProducts = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(`Before: ${allProducts}`)

allProducts.forEach((product, index) =>
  product == 3 && allProducts.unshift(allProducts.splice(index, 1)[0]));

console.log(`After: ${allProducts}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will indeed make the array longer while looping, which is a bad idea.

Instead you could use `sort` (for short code):

```
allProducts.sort((a, b) => checkIfProductIsMoreThen200(b.price) - 
                           checkIfProductIsMoreThen200(a.price));
```

For (very) long arrays, it will be more efficient to do this:

```
allProducts = allProducts.filter(a => checkIfProductIsMoreThen200(a.price)).concat(
    allProducts.filter(a => !checkIfProductIsMoreThen200(a.price))
);
```

Comment: Even if I provided a solution, I agree with @trincot that using `sort` is the best option